# Sum column with condition and display in row

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, calculated-columns

I would like to sum a column with multiple condition  and display all the result in rows

I have a table as

```
Status        Amount
pending         100
Success         50
pending         20
failure         80
success         20
```

Now I would like to find the total of pending, success and failure as

```
Pending        Success            failure
120             70                 80
```

something like

```
select sum(pending), sum(success), sum(failure) from mytable
```

Comment: this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7448/7) might give you answers

Comment: Can also use `SUM(IF (Status = 'pending', Status, 0))`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
   SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'pending' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Pending
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Success' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Success
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Failure' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Failure
FROM MyTable
```

You can also use this dynamic query:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(CASE WHEN `Status` = ''',
      `Status`,
      ''' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS `',
      `Status`, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM MyTable;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql,'
                     FROM MyTable
                  ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec54a/2)